# Why does my addArrays function get a wedge exit compile code? (UPDATE FIXED)

Tags: c

The rest of my functions work fabulously, however the last function has my goat. The goal of this function is to use pointers to obtain the values of two different arrays and add those values to a third array. However, when I run the main method to make the function run, it pauses for a second and provides a wedge exit code that does not work.

I've tried removing the if((sizeof(*ptr1)) == (sizeof(*ptr2)){
---insert code here---
}

from the for loop, however, the problem seems to be just the for loop itself.

```
//===================================Broken Code========================================
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM 1000


int sumArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[]);
int addArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[]); 

int main()
{

int arrayOne[MAXIMUM]; 
int arrayTwo[MAXIMUM];

for(int i = 0; i <= MAXIMUM; i++)

   arrayOne[i] = i;

printf("Arrayone %d\n", arrayOne);

for(int j = 0; j <= MAXIMUM; j++) 

      arrayTwo[j] = j;  

printf("ArrayTwo %d\n", arrayTwo);

printf(" The sum of the arrays is : %d\n",sumArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo));

printf("%d", addArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo));

return 0;
}

int sumArrays(int arr1[],int arr2[]){

int *ptr_1; 
int *ptr_2;

ptr_1 = &arr1[0]; 
ptr_2 = &arr2[0];

int sum; 

for(int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM; i++){

sum += *ptr_1 + i;
sum += *ptr_2 + i; 

} 

return sum; 
}

int addArrays(int arr1[],int arr2[]){

int *ptr1 = &arr1[0];
int *ptr2 = &arr2[0]; 
int sum = 0; 
int i = 0; 
int arr3[0];

if(sizeof(*ptr1) == sizeof(*ptr2)){

   for(int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM; i++){

      sum += *ptr1 +i;
      sum += *ptr2 +i;   
      arr3[i] = sum;

      }
   }

   printf("The value of array3 is %d", arr3); 
 }
```

The other function works perfectly, but the addArrays function does a wedge exit and doesn't cooperate.

I expect the addArrays function to take the elements from each array, add them together and assign them to the third array.

Thank you for your time.

***UPDATE: WORKING CODE***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM 1000

#define ARRAY_SZ(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))


int sumArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[], size_t len);
int addArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[], int arr3[], size_t len); 

int main()
{

int arrayOne[MAXIMUM]; 
int arrayTwo[MAXIMUM];
int arrayThree[MAXIMUM];

for(int i = 0; i <= MAXIMUM; i++)
   arrayOne[i] = i;

printf("Array One %d\n", ARRAY_SZ(arrayOne));

for(int j = 0; j <= MAXIMUM; j++) 
      arrayTwo[j] = j;  
printf("Array Two %d\n", ARRAY_SZ(arrayTwo));

printf(" The sum of the arrays is : %d\n",sumArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo, ARRAY_SZ(arrayOne)));
printf("%d", addArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree, MAXIMUM));
return 0;
}

int sumArrays(int arr1[],int arr2[], size_t len){

int *ptr_1; 
int *ptr_2;

ptr_1 = &arr1[0]; 
ptr_2 = &arr2[0];

int sum = 0 ; 

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
sum += *ptr_1++;
sum += *ptr_2++; 
} 

return sum; 
}

int addArrays(int arr1[],int arr2[], int result[], size_t len){

   int *ptr1 = &arr1[0];
      int *ptr2 = &arr2[0];
      int *ptr3 = &result[0]; 
         int sum = 0;
         int sum2 = 0; 
            int i = 0; 



   for(int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM; i++){
      sum = *ptr1 ++;
      sum += *ptr2 ++;   
      result[i] = sum;
      printf("The result of array 3 is %d\n", *ptr3++);
            }

 }
```

Comment: Please provide the exact exit code and message it emits.

Comment: You really need to format your code. It will be better for you and us.

Comment: Both `sizeof(*ptr1)` and `sizeof(*ptr2)` are constants.  Specifically, they are both equal to `sizeof(int)`.  So that test is always true.

Comment: Additionally, you cannot use `%d` to print an array. Arrays are not of type `int`

Comment: @torstenvl exit code for process is -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= MAXIMUM; i++) arrayOne[i] = i;` <<--  (and`sum`  is uninitialized in `sumarrays()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some notes:

When you assign/pass/print the and array using the name of the array, you are actually passing the memory location of the first element in the array (a pointer).So when you write:

```
printf("Arrayone %d\n", arrayOne);
```

You will see the memory address of the first element of the array being printed. If you would like to print the entire array you will need to loop through it. In this case you would be printing 1000 integers which might be undesirable.

```
void printArray(int * array, size_t len)
{
    while(len--)
    {
        printf("%d ", *array++);
    }
}
```

To get the number of elements in an array you can do something like this:

```
sizeof(arrayOne) / sizeof(arrayOne[0])
```

and you can put it in a macro like this:

```
#define ARRAY_SZ(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
```

and call it like this:

```
ARRAY_SZ(arrayOne);
```

You cannot get the array size if you are receiving an array in a function (it has decayed to a pointer), instead you should pass the array size to the function too. Here because you initialize the arrays with the size `MAXIMUM` we don't actually need to calculate the array size, but we can just to show it works.

If you want to return an array (like in `addArrays()`) you should create an empty array and pass it to the function, then the function can update the array with the result.

When looping through an array you never want to do `array[maximum]` because the array indices range from `0` to `maximum - 1`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM 1000

#define ARRAY_SZ(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

int sumArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[]);
int addArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[]); 

int main()
{
    int arrayOne[MAXIMUM]; 
    int arrayTwo[MAXIMUM];
    int arrayThree[MAXIMUM];

    for(int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM; i++)
       arrayOne[i] = i;

    printf("Array one size %d\n", ARRAY_SZ(arrayOne));

    for(int j = 0; j < MAXIMUM; j++) 
          arrayTwo[j] = j;  
    printf("Array Two size %d\n", ARRAY_SZ(arrayTwo));

    printf(" The sum of the arrays is : %d\n",sumArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo, ARRAY_SZ(arrayOne)));
    addArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree, MAXIMUM);
    return 0;
}

int sumArrays(int arr1[],int arr2[], size_t len)
{
    int *ptr_1; 
    int *ptr_2;

    ptr_1 = &arr1[0]; 
    ptr_2 = &arr2[0];

    int sum; 

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        sum += *ptr_1 + i;
        sum += *ptr_2 + i; 
    } 

    return sum; 
}

void addArrays(int arr1[], int arr2[], int result[], size_t len){

   int *ptr1 = arr1;
   int *ptr2 = arr2; 
   int sum = 0; 
   int i = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
      sum = *ptr1 +i;
      sum += *ptr2 +i;   
      result[i] = sum;
   }

 }
```

Comment: Happy to help, please look over and if you are unclear why something was changed or what is happening ask here

Comment: I did not compile or test so there could be problems

Comment: Liam, question. How does that ARRAY_SZ macro work, exactly? It's brilliant, but I'm not exactly sure how to explain. Is it the same thing as taking 1000/1 ?

Comment: First of all it is not my invention, it's very popular. `sizeof(arr)` is the total number of bytes in the array, in your case `1000 * sizeof(int)` because you have 1000 integers, integers are often 4 bytes long (machine dependant). `sizeof(arr[0])` is the size of the first element in the array, in you case an integer. So if you divide the size of the total array by the size of each element you get the number of elements

Comment: Assuming an integer is 4 bytes you are doing `4000/4`